# create geometry collection by existing geometry column in mysql

Tags: mysql, geometry, geospatial

I try to figure out, if there is the possibilty to create a geometry collection from an exisitng geometry-column with 1000 entrys or more, by the use of an SQL select-statment in MySQL. Any Ideas?

Thanks for answering

(please no PHP, Perl, etc. solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by converting your geometry objects to text in the [WKT format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkt-format), manipulating them, and converting them back to the internal format.

Judicious use of MySQL functions like [GeomFromText](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/populating-spatial-columns.html)(), [AsText](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_astext)(), CONCAT(), GROUP_CONCAT(), and string processing functions should make it possible to gather up multiple items and create new ones.

If you have 1000 objects you want in one single collection, you will run into a [string-length limitation in GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).  You will need to change the group_concat_max_len system variable.

This SQL isn't going to be very beautiful, eh? It certainly isn't going to be easy to debug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it would be easier, if I use a server-side-scripting language like PHP to create my geometry collection. Too bad, that there is no related function ST_Collect() as it is implemented in PostgreeSQL + PostGIS extension.

Comment: Yes, you are right that `ST_Collect()` would be awesome.